# Error while consuming one WCF Service (hosted on Windows Service) from another WCF Service (self hosted)

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, service, wcf-hosting

I am hosting a WCF service on Windows Service (let's call it WCF B) and then trying to consume it from another WCF service (which is self hosted) (let's call it WCF A).

[image]

I am able to add service reference perfectly, end points are getting auto generated properly. But when I am trying to instantiate the client object.

I am communicating over TCP. I am getting following error.

[image: Error Message, when I try to instantiate the client service object]

Configuration Code of WCF B is as below

[image]

Auto generated Endpoint details(After adding Service Reference) in WCF A web.config are as below.

[image]

Comment: You mean App.config, right? Because you said it's a console app.

Comment: After build, check the bin/debug or bin/release folder and open yourapp.exe.config. Is the client endpoint configuration there?

Comment: WCF A is hosted on Console app. But WCF B's service reference is added in WCF Service A's project not in Console app(host) project. Do I need to add service reference in Console app(host) project?

Comment: You said that A consumes B, right? So, the client configuration for B should be in A's config. That makes sense.

Comment: Yes. Let me check .exe.config quickly.

Comment: Marcel, your inputs were very crucial, they gave me a direction and I could solve the problem. We have to paste endpoint information in host app.config as well.

Comment: Client endpoints need to be on the consuming side. Must have been some confusion going on when you created the reference

Comment: But, it is trying to read end point details from app.config of host.

Comment: After pasting those details to host, it is working

Comment: Hi there. Just so you know, code is best rendered as text on sites like Stack Overflow - here we have code formatting tools as well. This makes it much easier for people to copy and paste what you provide - which is not possible with images.

Answer (score 0):

We have to copy the endpoint details from our WCF A web.config and paste them into it's host (Console app.config in this case)

Information to be copy pasted is configuration which is auto generated after adding Service Reference.

[image]